# Google API Client for JS, Gapi.Client vs Gapi.Auth2

Tags: google-api, google-signin

Working with the `gapi` google api client for javascript. We have our current operations working atop `gapi.client` which we can hold the tokens for the user and simply supply them to `gapi.client` prior to running operations.

The issue is that for additional functions with other API's, we need to use a process with the `gapi.auth2` object that grants the additional permissions. We have the tokens, and the user's consent, but calling `gapi.auth2.init` seems to force another signin.

Example: `gapi.client.setToken({access_token: access});`

How can I set the tokens we already have in `gapi.auth2` so that I can perform the grant?